# python pip install is not installing under the right python version

Tags: python, pip

```
workon dal                                                               ✭ ✱
(dal)➜  Server (master)
```

checking that the python version is correct

```
pyenv versions                                                           ✭ ✱
  system
  2.7
  3.2.1
* 3.4.2 (set by /Volumes/dev/Backend/DAL/Server/.python-version)
  venv34
```

but when installing , it installing under 2.7 and not 3.4.2

```
(dal)➜  Server (master) pip install -r requirements.txt                                          ✭ ✱
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.10.1 in /Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
...
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stevedore==1.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 13))
```

notice the **python2.7** in the path.

how do I tell pip to install it under 3.4.2?

edit:
tried, for example

```
(dal)➜  Server (master) pip3 install itsdangerous
```

and it installs it under the main python env and not specifically in the `dal` virtualenv.
proof:
(dal)➜  Server (master) pip3 install itsdangerous                                                ✭ ✱

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

edit2:

when typing 
`eval "$(pyenv init -)"`
as recommended in pyenv guide , I see the
python --version 
Python 3.4.2
but then , when enterin to pyhton console

```
 python                                                                ✭ ✱
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 19 2014, 06:00:59)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: it seems to install it under the general python and not in the virtualenv (dal in this case).

Comment: wrote the output in the question body

Comment: if python points to the correct interpreter, you can use `python -m pip install itsdangerous` to make sure you call the `pip` binary that belongs to your python interpreter.

Comment: `(dal)➜  Server (master) which python                                                             ✭ ✱
/Users/partuck/.virtualenvs/dal/bin/python` how do I know which python it is? i think it's 2.7

Comment: try `python --version`

Comment: `python --version                                                    ✭ ✱
Python 2.7.9` how do I switch to 3.4?

Comment: did you add `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to your `~/.bash_profile` as suggested in the installation guide? https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv